# Time measurement with SLURM

Tags: slurm

I have created many programs from which I want to measure how long it takes to complete. Therefore I want to run one task on one node. We have 10 nodes and each node has 2 sockets. No matter what options I pass to sbatch and srun, SLURM seems to schedule 1 task per socket instead of 1 task per node. What options should I use?

I start my batch script with `sbatch run-experiments`

`run-experiments` contains:

```
#SBATCH -N10 --ntasks-per-node=1
...
for 1..1000 do
    srun -N1 -n1 --exclusive task &
done
```

Edit: it seems the problem only occurs on one partition and not on another. Is there a configuration setting which may cause this?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer exactly your question, but I think you are missing a "wait" after the "done" in your script. Without the wait, your sbatch will return immediately after having submited the last job without giving time to some of the tasks to finish.

For your problem, you needs to check the "Shared" parameter in the partition definition.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have

```
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_CORE
```

in your slurm.conf,

This 2 lines defines the resource selection for the upcoming jobs.
Its tested on slurm version slurm 17.11.7 and used the following slurm.conf

```
#
# Example slurm.conf file. Please run configurator.html
# (in doc/html) to build a configuration file customized
# for your environment.
#
#
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.
#
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
ClusterName=kaleidoscope
ControlMachine=headnode
#
SlurmUser=slurm
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPort=6818
AuthType=auth/munge
#
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm/ctld
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurm/d
SwitchType=switch/none
MpiDefault=none
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
#
# TIMERS
SlurmctldTimeout=300
SlurmdTimeout=300
InactiveLimit=0
MinJobAge=300
KillWait=30
Waittime=0
#
# SCHEDULING
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
FastSchedule=1
#
# LOGGING
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurmd.log
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#
# COMPUTE NODES
#
PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=MEMLOCK
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/filetxt
Epilog=/etc/slurm/slurm.epilog.clean
NodeName=node[1-2] Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=1 ThreadsPerCore=1 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=normal Nodes=node[1-2] Default=YES MaxTime=24:00:00 State=UP
ReturnToService=1

#SelectType=select/cons_res
#SelectTypeParameters=CR_CORE
```